# Accessing a private variable from another class

Tags: java, variables, reflection, private

NOTE: I have looked at the other posts, but I'm still quite lost.

This is the code for a private variable that I have in one class:

```
private int readFile( String fileName)  
{
 try
 {
            File f = new File( fileName );
            Scanner input = new Scanner( f );
            while( input.hasNextLine( ) )
            {
                    String s = input.nextLine( );
                    String[ ] sArr = s.split( " " );
                    String animal = sArr[ 0 ];
                    double cost = Double.parseDouble(sArr [ 1 ] );
                    boolean penNeeded = Boolean.parseBoolean( sArr[ 2 ] );
                    boolean available = Boolean.parseBoolean( sArr[ 3 ] );
                    Pet p = new Pet( animal, cost, penNeeded, available );
                    if (count < animalList.length )
                    {
                       animalList[count] = p;
                       count++;
                    }
            }
            input.close( );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
          System.out.println("Error reading the file:");
          System.out.println( e );
          e.printStackTrace(  );
        }

        return count;
  }
```

I need to access it in this piece of code located in another class:

```
 static public void processTransaction( String fileName, PettingZoo pz )
 {
    try
    {
       // variable should be accessed here                  
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading the file:");
        System.out.println( e );
        e.printStackTrace(  );
    }
}
```

How can I do this? I think that I need to use a modifier of some sort, but I don't know how which one or how to implement it.

Comment: Can you declare the variable outside of your method and then create a getter/setter method for that variable?

Comment: I didnt get your question. I guess you want to access `private int readFile(String fileName)` method? not field right?

Comment: *What* "private variable"? You show a method declared `private` ... which means you *can't* access it from another class.

Comment: You have to use gettter and setter

Comment: @Jayamohan yes, that is the method that I want to access.

Answer (score 2):

If you want access to a private variable, you can use getter and setter methods.

Example:

```
private int variable = 5; //<--- your private variable of class A

// a public method (into the same class A)
// that allows the sharing of your private variable
public int getVariable() {
    return variable;
}
```

Now you can call the method `getVariable()` from an other class (B) and take the value of the private variable (of class A).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly access private variables from another class.  That's the whole point of declaring it private.  What you need to do is use `setter` and `getter` methods in class `A`, then call the `get` method from class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672331/accessing-a-private-variable-from-another-class/20673237#comment30955808_20672331) you can access the `private int readFile(String fileName)` method by changing the modified of the method. Change the modifier of the method to `public` or `protected`. Also since the accessing method is `static` you need to change the method as `static`.

So change it as

```
public static int readFile( String fileName)  
{

}
```

In the `processTransaction` method invoke it as,

```
ClassName.readFile("file_name.extn");
```